# Fortran arctan subroutine is not working as expected

Tags: fortran, subroutine

I'm generally new to Fortran, and I have a project in which my professor wants the class to try to find pi. To do this he wants us to create our own arctan subroutine and use this specific equation: pi = 16*arctan(1/5) - 4*arctan(1/239).

Because the professor would not let me use the built in `ATAN` function, I made a subroutine that approximates it:

```
subroutine arctan(x,n,arc)
    real*8::x, arc
    integer::n, i
    real*8::num, nm2
    arc = 0.0
    do i=1,n,4
    num = i
    nm2 = num+2
    arc = arc+((x**num)/(num)) - (x**(nm2)/(nm2))
    enddo
    end subroutine arctan
```

This subroutine is based off of the Taylor series for arctan approximation, and seemed to work perfectly because I tested it by calling this.

```
real*8:: arc=0.0, approx
call arctan(1.d0,10000000,arc)
approx = arc*4
```

I called this from my main program which should return pi and I got

```
approx = 3.1415926335902506
```

which is close enough for me. The problem occurs when I try to do

pi = 16*arctan(1/5) - 4*arctan(1/239). I tried this:

```
real*8:: first, second
integer:: n=100
    call arctan((1.d0/5.d0), n, arc)
    first = 16*arc
    call arctan((1.d0/239.d0), n, arc)
    second = 4.d0*arc
    approx = first - second
```

and somehow `approx = 1.67363040082988898E-002`, which is obviously not pi. arc resets with every call of the arctan subroutine so I know that isn't the problem. I think the problem is in how I'm calling the subroutine before I declare `first` and `second`, but I don't know what I could do to improve them.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I actually solved the problem and the actual problem was just fortran decided that it did not want to do `approx = first - second`
and was making it so that approx == second I have no idea why, but I solved the problem by replacing that statement with the following:

```
approx = (second-first)
approx = approx *(-1)
```

and as stupid as it looks, it works perfectly now, with a result of 3.1415926535897940!

Comment: Your problem could have something to do with the way you're passing the number of iterations `n` into your arctan function. Firstly, it shouldn't be the caller's responsibility to guess how many terms in the Taylor series is needed for convergence. Secondly, however, you may find that by adding up a billion (!) terms, you actually introduce much more round-off error than if you terminated the series after a much more modest number of terms. If you only need to calculate arctan(1/5) (or smaller), then the series should converge pretty swiftly.

Comment: In the "wrong example did you declare arc? make it a MWE (Minimal Working Example) that can be compiled and run.

Comment: I think in this case `IMPLICIT NONE` in the code or `-fimplicit-none` on the command line might be your friend.

Comment: If you are learning Fortran don't use real*8 - it isn't part of Fortran and have never been part of Fortran. Learn about the Fortran kind mechanism instead, which is how this should be done.

Comment: note it would be not only legal, but preferable, to use integer types for the exponents.

Comment: @agentp's comment is a good one.  Especially in light of the fact that with `num` a real and `x` negative, `x**num` is not allowed by the Fortran standard.

Comment: I apologize, that was a typo. the professor specifically asked for a subroutine. I don't really know why.

Comment: your "fix" is totally unnecessary. My guess you originally had a variable name spelled wrong (which is one reason to always use `implicit none`)

Comment: I have very much doubts about your "fix", this would be a MAJOR compiler bug. As you didn't post your code we cannot see what really went wrong (and what you might have changed more, without you remembering it / not written in your edit).

Answer (score 0):

The problem results from different types (single/double precsion) of the
variable arc in the call of arctan and the implementation of the subroutine. The iteration count of 10000... is way too much and may cause numerical problems, just 100 is more than enough (and much faster...).

Tip: always use implicit none for all progs and procedures. Here the compiler would have immediately told you that you forgot to declare arc...

Just make it double precision in the main program and you will get the desired answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I made sure to change arc to double precision, and added implicit none to my program and subroutine. I also changed my n to 100. Unfortunately I am still getting 1.67363040082988898E-002  as my answer.

Comment: @ArashiNakamura Please provide the minimal full code that shows the problem, i.e the small main program with the called subroutine and that we can run.